# Yield all root-to-leaf branches of a Binary Tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, binary-tree

Sorry if this is a common question but I haven't found an appropriate answer for my particular problem. I'm trying to implement a `walk` method that walks a binary tree from its root node to each of its leaf nodes, yielding the root-to-leaf path whenever I get to a leaf node. For example, walking the binary tree represented by:

```
     __a__
    /     \
   b       d
  / \     / \
 -   c   -   -
```

Would yield:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'd']
```

My idea is that `BinaryTree.walk` calls `Node.traverse` on the root node, which in turn calls the `traverse`method of each child node recursively. `BinaryTree.walk` also creates an empty list which is passed around with each `traverse` call, appending the data of each node, yielding the list once a leaf node is reached and popping each element out of the list after visiting each node.

At some point, something is going wrong though. This is my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.data})"

    @property
    def children(self):
        return self.left, self.right

    def traverse(self, branch):
        print('ON NODE:', self)
        branch.append(self.data)
        if self.left is None and self.right is None:
            yield branch
        else:
            for child in self.children:
                if child is not None:
                    print('ENTERING CHILD:', child)
                    child.traverse(branch=branch)
                    print('EXITING CHILD:', child)
                    branch.pop()


class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, root=Node()):
        if not isinstance(root, Node):
            raise ValueError(f"Tree root must be Node, not {type(root)}")
        self.root = root

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.root})"

    def walk(self):
        node = self.root
        branch = []
        yield from node.traverse(branch=branch)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create root node
    n0 = Node('A')
    # create binary tree with root node
    tree = BinaryTree(root=n0)
    # create others nodes
    n1 = Node(data='B')
    n2 = Node(data='C')
    n3 = Node(data='D')
    # connect nodes
    n0.left = n1
    n0.right = n3
    n1.right = n2

    # walk tree and yield branches
    for branch in tree.walk():
        print(branch)
```

### Expected output:

```
ON NODE: Node(A)
ENTERING CHILD: Node(B)
ON NODE: Node(B)
ENTERING CHILD: Node(C)
ON NODE: Node(C)
['A', 'B', 'C']  # yielded branch
EXITING CHILD: Node(C)
EXITING CHILD: Node(B)
ENTERING CHILD: Node(D)
ON NODE: Node(D)
['A', 'D']  # yielded branch
EXITING CHILD: Node(D)
```

### Actual output:

```
ON NODE: Node(A)
ENTERING CHILD: Node(B)
EXITING CHILD: Node(B)
ENTERING CHILD: Node(D)
EXITING CHILD: Node(D)
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

I understand I'm doing something wrong with the list since it's trying to pop when it's empty, but I can't understand how it got to that. It should call `pop` once for each `append` call.

Also I can't figure out why the nodes are being entered and exited, but the `ON NODE:` message is not being printed... It's like my code just skips the `child.traverse(branch=branch)` line somehow?

Can anyone help me understand where I'm messing this up?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modified variant of your code.

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys


class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.data})"

    @property
    def children(self):
        if self.left:
            yield self.left
        if self.right:
            yield self.right

    @property
    def is_leaf(self):
        return self.left is None and self.right is None

    def traverse_preord(self, accumulator=list()):
        print("  On node:", self)
        accumulator.append(self.data)
        if self.is_leaf:
            yield accumulator
        else:
            for child in self.children:
                print("  Entering child:", child)
                yield from child.traverse_preord(accumulator=accumulator)
                accumulator.pop()
                print("  Exiting child:", child)


def main():
    root = Node(data="A",
                left=Node(data="B",
                          right=Node(data="C")
                         ),
                right=Node(data="D",
                           #left=Node(data="E"),
                           #right=Node(data="F"),
                          )
               )
    for path in root.traverse_preord():
        print("Found path:", path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- I refactored the code a bit (simplified, changed some identifier names, texts and other insignificant changes)
- *children* property:

  - *None* for a node's *left* or *right* attribute, means that the node has no child, so no point including it in the returned result
  - Since the question is involving *yield*, I turned it into a generator (instead of returning a tuple or list, ...). As a consequence, I had to add *is_leaf*, since a generator doesn't evaluate to *False* (even if empty)

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q055424449]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
>   On node: Node(A)
>   Entering child: Node(B)
>   On node: Node(B)
>   Entering child: Node(C)
>   On node: Node(C)
> Found path: ['A', 'B', 'C']
>   Exiting child: Node(C)
>   Exiting child: Node(B)
>   Entering child: Node(D)
>   On node: Node(D)
> Found path: ['A', 'D']
>   Exiting child: Node(D)
> ```

### What is wrong with your code?

It's the *traverse* recurring call (`child.traverse(branch=branch)`). **It created a generator, but since that wasn't used (iterated on) anywhere, the function didn't actually called itself**, resulting in the attempt of removing more elements than added (only ***1***: which is the root node). 
So, it turns out that you were almost there. All you have to do, is adding a **`yield from`** in front of it :). 
More details on [[Python]: PEP 380 -- Syntax for Delegating to a Subgenerator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380).

Comment: Thanks so much - this is exactly what I needed! Great answer, explanation and examples. As you said it works perfectly just by adding the `yield from`, although I'll definitely refactor a bit too - I like your `children` property, it makes sense. I can't award the bounty just yet but I'll do it as soon as the waiting period is over, you more than earned it! :)

Comment: You're welcome!. Do not worry about the bounty, it's not the reason why I chose this question (although if the bounty wasn't there, I might have skipped it, as there's no way someone could monitor all the questions), it was an exercise for me as well!

Answer (score 1):

There is a great answer [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-binary-tree-print-all-root-to-leaf-paths/)

Copying their Python example:

```
""" 
Python program to print all path from root to 
leaf in a binary tree 
"""

# binary tree node contains data field ,  
# left and right pointer 
class Node: 
    # constructor to create tree node 
    def __init__(self, data): 
        self.data = data 
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

# function to print all path from root 
# to leaf in binary tree 
def printPaths(root): 
    # list to store path 
    path = [] 
    printPathsRec(root, path, 0) 

# Helper function to print path from root  
# to leaf in binary tree 
def printPathsRec(root, path, pathLen): 

    # Base condition - if binary tree is 
    # empty return 
    if root is None: 
        return

    # add current root's data into  
    # path_ar list 

    # if length of list is gre 
    if(len(path) > pathLen):  
        path[pathLen] = root.data 
    else: 
        path.append(root.data) 

    # increment pathLen by 1 
    pathLen = pathLen + 1

    if root.left is None and root.right is None: 

        # leaf node then print the list 
        printArray(path, pathLen) 
    else: 
        # try for left and right subtree 
        printPathsRec(root.left, path, pathLen) 
        printPathsRec(root.right, path, pathLen) 

# Helper function to print list in which  
# root-to-leaf path is stored 
def printArray(ints, len): 
    for i in ints[0 : len]: 
        print(i," ",end="") 
    print() 

# Driver program to test above function 
""" 
Constructed binary tree is  
      10 
    /   \ 
   8     2 
  / \   / 
 3   5 2 
"""
root = Node(10) 
root.left = Node(8) 
root.right = Node(2) 
root.left.left = Node(3) 
root.left.right = Node(5) 
root.right.left = Node(2) 
printPaths(root) 

# This code has been contributed by Shweta Singh.
```

Gives:

> 10  8  3
>   10  8  5
>   10  2  2

You can give it letters like you have too:

```
root = Node("A") 
root.left = Node("B") 
root.right = Node("D") 
root.left.right = Node("C") 
printPaths(root)
```

Gives:

> A B C
>   A D

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had found this link when searching for an answer, and I actually managed to implement this code to my case, but I didn't really understand what it is doing. It feels to me like it has too many auxiliary functions...? And a couple variables like `pathLen` which I'm not sure what's the point. I was hoping to implement in a more "straightforward" way (at least from my point of view) using `yield` statements. I'll definitely give it another chance if I don't understand what's the problem with my example, tho. Thanks again :)