# How to Parse Data from SciKitLearn Agglomerative Clustering

Tags: python, matplotlib, d3.js, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering

I feel like very similar versions of this question have been asked, and I have learned a lot while trying to solve this problem, but there is some (probably very basic) concept that I am missing.

Here are three very similar question/answers that are very good:

[Extract path from root to leaf in sklearn's agglomerative clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57638604/extract-path-from-root-to-leaf-in-sklearns-agglomerative-clustering)

[Yield all root-to-leaf branches of a Binary Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55424449/yield-all-root-to-leaf-branches-of-a-binary-tree?rq=1)

[How do you visualize a ward tree from sklearn.cluster.ward_tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106425/how-do-you-visualize-a-ward-tree-from-sklearn-cluster-ward-tree?rq=1)

And there is some great stuff on Mike Bostock's D3 Git: [Mike Bostock's D3 Git Repo](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#tree)

**Now the specifics of my situation:**

I have done some analysis in Python using sklearn Agglomerative Clustering.  I am generating the dendrograms I would like to see in MatplotLib:

T=7
[T=7 Dendrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4udUt.png)

T=2
[T=2 Dendrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTQ5X.png)

Now I would like to add those dendrograms and some other functionality to a web site.  I have built a site using Django.

I have used some D3 Javascript functionality already to implement a dynamic and interactive Tree Diagram like this one:

https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092

And I have made it so it loads the information for each branch from a json file. So it is both dynamic and interactive.
[Interactive Tree Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7Y3g.png)

Now I want to mimic some of that functionality with the info from the Agglomerative Clustering.

**I want to:**

1. **Make a dendrogram similar to the one from MatplotLib, and make it
   interactive such that there should be a slider that allows the user
   to change the T value, and the dendrogram should redraw.**

   A. I am open to any suggestions.  I can brute force a solution by simply recalculating the dendrogram in Python (as a module inside
   Django app), saving an image and loading that image on the
   javascript side in the template.  I think there is probably a more
   elegant solution with D3 but I am running out of time to do
   research.
2. **Create an interactive Tree Diagram using the info from the clustering.**
   I would like to see the dendrogram far more interactive as a tree.  It seems like I should be able to use either the agglo_model.children_  or the linkage_matrix.

```
agglo_model.children_: 
[[ 35  36][ 13  18][ 19  20]...[ 22  69][ 33  34][ 14  32]]

or the linkage_matrix:
linkage_matrix: 
[[ 35.          36.           0.           2.        ]
 [ 22.          69.           1.73205081   4.        ]
...
 [ 50.          57.           4.47213595   2.        ]
 [  9.          41.           4.69041576   2.        ]
...
 [116.         126.          12.62713128  36.        ]
 [128.         129.          17.97652791  66.        ]]
```

**The key piece I am missing is how to go from scikit to the following tree format for d3.js**

```
    var treeData = [
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "parent": "Top Level",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: B",
        "parent": "Top Level"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

3. Show a clustering diagram on the web page.  Basicially I'd like to mimic this page: [Agglomerative Clustering and MatplotLib Diagrams and Dendrograms](https://stackabuse.com/hierarchical-clustering-with-python-and-scikit-learn/) with interactive javascript.

Again - any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Please let me know if there's anything I can do to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot to this question but I think it boils down to how can one get the data from a linkage matrix into a `d3` tree diagram?

Given this python code:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
   
X = np.array([[5,3],
    [10,15],
    [15,12],
    [24,10],
    [30,30],
    [85,70],
    [71,80],
    [60,78],
    [70,55],
    [80,91],])

linked = linkage(X, "single")

labelList = range(0, 10)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
dendrogram(linked,
            orientation='top',
            labels=labelList,
            distance_sort='descending',
            show_leaf_counts=False)
plt.show()
```

Which generates this linkage matrix:

```
[[ 1.          2.          5.83095189  2.        ]
 [ 3.         10.          9.21954446  3.        ]
 [ 6.          7.         11.18033989  2.        ]
 [ 0.         11.         13.          4.        ]
 [ 9.         12.         14.2126704   3.        ]
 [ 5.         14.         17.20465053  4.        ]
 [ 4.         13.         20.88061302  5.        ]
 [ 8.         15.         21.21320344  5.        ]
 [16.         17.         47.16990566 10.        ]]
```

And this dendrogram:

[image]

How then can we then convert the linkage matrix into a data structure compatible for the `d3` tree?  Now it took me a bit to grok the structure of the matrix and how it was conveying hierarchy.  This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37712929/16363) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40983611/16363) really explain it well.  So, let's do a little data manipulation in Python and then JSON-ify it out.  If you are using Django, you can return this JSON via API call.

```
import json

def create_tree(linked):
    ## inner func to recurvise-ly walk the linkage matrix
    def recurTree(tree):
        k = tree['name']
        ## no children for this node
        if k not in inter:
            return
        for n in inter[k]:
            ## build child nodes
            node = {
                "name": n,
                "parent": k,
                "children": []
            }
            ## add to children
            tree['children'].append(node)
            ## next recursion
            recurTree(node)      
    
    num_rows, _ = linked.shape
    inter = {}
    i = 0
    // loop linked matrix convert to dictionary
    for row in linked:
        i += 1
        inter[float(i + num_rows)] = [row[0],row[1]]

    // start tree data structure
    tree = {
        "name": float(i + num_rows),
        "parent": None,
        "children": []
    }
    // start recursion
    recurTree(tree);
    return tree

print(json.dumps(create_tree(linked), indent = 2))
```

This produces JSON like so:

```
{
  "name": 18.0,
  "parent": null,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": 16.0,
      "parent": 18.0,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": 4.0,
          "parent": 16.0,
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": 13.0,
          "parent": 16.0,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": 0.0,
              "parent": 13.0,
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "name": 11.0,
              "parent": 13.0,
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": 3.0,
                  "parent": 11.0,
                  "children": []
                },
                {
                  "name": 10.0,
                  "parent": 11.0,
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": 1.0,
                      "parent": 10.0,
                      "children": []
                    },
                    {
                      "name": 2.0,
                      "parent": 10.0,
                      "children": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": 17.0,
      "parent": 18.0,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": 8.0,
          "parent": 17.0,
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": 15.0,
          "parent": 17.0,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": 5.0,
              "parent": 15.0,
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "name": 14.0,
              "parent": 15.0,
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": 9.0,
                  "parent": 14.0,
                  "children": []
                },
                {
                  "name": 12.0,
                  "parent": 14.0,
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": 6.0,
                      "parent": 12.0,
                      "children": []
                    },
                    {
                      "name": 7.0,
                      "parent": 12.0,
                      "children": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If we then dump that into the `d3` tree example (I made it vertical), you end up with this:

[image]

Running code for `d3`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Tree Example</title>

    <style>
      .node {
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .node circle {
        fill: #fff;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 3px;
      }

      .node text {
        font: 12px sans-serif;
      }

      .link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- load the d3.js library -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      var treeData = {
        name: 18.0,
        parent: null,
        children: [
          {
            name: 16.0,
            parent: 18.0,
            children: [
              {
                name: 4.0,
                parent: 16.0,
                children: [],
              },
              {
                name: 13.0,
                parent: 16.0,
                children: [
                  {
                    name: 0.0,
                    parent: 13.0,
                    children: [],
                  },
                  {
                    name: 11.0,
                    parent: 13.0,
                    children: [
                      {
                        name: 3.0,
                        parent: 11.0,
                        children: [],
                      },
                      {
                        name: 10.0,
                        parent: 11.0,
                        children: [
                          {
                            name: 1.0,
                            parent: 10.0,
                            children: [],
                          },
                          {
                            name: 2.0,
                            parent: 10.0,
                            children: [],
                          },
                        ],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 17.0,
            parent: 18.0,
            children: [
              {
                name: 8.0,
                parent: 17.0,
                children: [],
              },
              {
                name: 15.0,
                parent: 17.0,
                children: [
                  {
                    name: 5.0,
                    parent: 15.0,
                    children: [],
                  },
                  {
                    name: 14.0,
                    parent: 15.0,
                    children: [
                      {
                        name: 9.0,
                        parent: 14.0,
                        children: [],
                      },
                      {
                        name: 12.0,
                        parent: 14.0,
                        children: [
                          {
                            name: 6.0,
                            parent: 12.0,
                            children: [],
                          },
                          {
                            name: 7.0,
                            parent: 12.0,
                            children: [],
                          },
                        ],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      };

      // ************** Generate the tree diagram    *****************
      var margin = { top: 40, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120 },
        width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
        height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      var i = 0;

      var tree = d3.layout.tree().size([height, width]);

      var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal().projection(function (d) {
        return [d.x, d.y];
      });

      var svg = d3
        .select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

      root = treeData;

      update(root);

      function update(source) {
        // Compute the new tree layout.
        var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
          links = tree.links(nodes);

        // Normalize for fixed-depth.
        nodes.forEach(function (d) {
          d.y = d.depth * 100;
        });

        // Declare the nodes…
        var node = svg.selectAll('g.node').data(nodes, function (d) {
          return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
        });

        // Enter the nodes.
        var nodeEnter = node
          .enter()
          .append('g')
          .attr('class', 'node')
          .attr('transform', function (d) {
            return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
          });

        nodeEnter.append('circle').attr('r', 10).style('fill', '#fff');

        nodeEnter
          .append('text')
          .attr('y', function (d) {
            return d.children || d._children ? -18 : 18;
          })
          .attr('dy', '.35em')
          .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
          .text(function (d) {
            return d.name;
          })
          .style('fill-opacity', 1);

        // Declare the links…
        var link = svg.selectAll('path.link').data(links, function (d) {
          return d.target.id;
        });

        // Enter the links.
        link
          .enter()
          .insert('path', 'g')
          .attr('class', 'link')
          .attr('d', diagonal);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is one FANTASTIC ANSWER!  Your reputation is well earned!  This is exactly what I needed!